# Python: Accessing list in dictionary in different function

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I am making a simple program where you can view, add or remove gifts from different persons. 
I am trying to access and edit a list in a dictionary named people{} from a different function.
How can I do it?

```
def people():

    people = {"Alan":["skate","computer"],
              "John":["sweater","socks"]}

    print("""Select one option:

    1. Alan
    2. John""")

    gifts(people)

def gifts(people):

    person = input()

    if person == "1":
        print("The gifts of Alan are: %s" % people["Alan"])
        return person
        gift_options() 

    elif person == "2":
        print("The gifts of John are: %s" % people["John"])
        return person
        gift_options()
    else:
        people()

def gift_manage(person):

    print ("""Select an option:

    1. Add gift
    2. Remove gift
    3. Return to list of availible people""")

    option = input()

    if option == "1":
        print ("What gift would you like to add to %s? " % person)
        new_gift = input()
        people[person].append(str(new_gift))
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing it ok. If you are receiving an error message then you should update the question with the text of the whole traceback.

Comment: @babygame0ver Concerning your proposed edit, I am pretty sure the OP is writing in Python3. Please do not add old Python 2.7 syntax to his code. `raw_input` is just `input` in Python3.

Comment: yeah but there was a problem in the variable name and stackoverflow have a rule that you should edit the post if the wrong characters >=6.

Comment: Ok, I've done the edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
def people_gifts():

    people = {"Alan":["skate","computer"],
              "John":["sweater","socks"]}

    print("""Select one option:

    1. Alan
    2. John""")

    #gifts(people)
    return people

def gifts(people):

    person = input()

    if person == "1":
        print("The gifts of Alan are: %s" % people["Alan"])
        return person

    elif person == "2":
        print("The gifts of John are: %s" % people["John"])
        return person
    else:
        people_gifts()

def gift_manage(person,people): 
    print("\n\n")
    print(person,"has",people[person])
    print ("""Select an option:

    1. Add gift
    2. Remove gift
    3. Return to list of availible people
    4. Quit""")

    option = input()

    if option == "1":
        print ("What gift would you like to add to %s? " % person)
        new_gift = input()
        people[person].append(str(new_gift))
        print ("gift added",people[person])

    elif option == "2":
        print ("What gift would you like to remove to %s? " % person)
        remove_gift = input()
        if(remove_gift in people[person]):

            people[person].remove(str(remove_gift))
            print ("gift removed",people[person])
        else:
            print ("Sorry gift does not exist")

    elif option == "3":
        print ("Available people : ",list(people.keys()))

    elif option == "4":
        print ("Exiting...")
        return people

    else:
        print ("Try again")
        gift_manage(person,people)

    print("Do you want to try again? Press 1")
    choice=input()
    if(choice=="1"):
        gift_manage(person,people)
    return people


people=people_gifts()
gifts(people)
gift_manage("Alan",people)
```

Adding a gift

[image: Adding a gift]

Removing a valid gift

[image: Removing a valid gift]

Removing invalid gift

[image: Removing invalid gift]